# Json references during deserialization with custom ReferenceResolver get lost

Tags: c#, deserialization, system.text.json

I implemented a custom ReferenceResolver as shown from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/preserve-references)

During serialization the $ids and $refs are added to the JSON correctly.

But during deserialization the $refs are not resolved.

This is my Resolver:

```
public class JsonReferenceResolver : ReferenceResolver
{
    private uint _referenceCount;
    private readonly Dictionary<string, object> _referenceIdToObjectMap = new();
    private readonly Dictionary<object, string> _objectToReferenceIdMap = new(ReferenceEqualityComparer.Instance);

    public override void AddReference(string referenceId, object value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Add Ref: " + referenceId);
        if (!_referenceIdToObjectMap.TryAdd(referenceId, value))
        {
            throw new JsonException();
        }
    }

    public override string GetReference(object value, out bool alreadyExists)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Get Ref: " + value);

        if (_objectToReferenceIdMap.TryGetValue(value, out string? referenceId))
        {
            alreadyExists = true;
        }
        else
        {
            _referenceCount++;
            referenceId = _referenceCount.ToString();
            _objectToReferenceIdMap.Add(value, referenceId);
            alreadyExists = false;
        }

        return referenceId;
    }

    public override object ResolveReference(string referenceId)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Res Ref: " + referenceId);
        if (!_referenceIdToObjectMap.TryGetValue(referenceId, out object? value))
        {
            throw new JsonException();
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

And this is my RefereceHandler:

```
public class JsonReferenceHandler : ReferenceHandler
{
    public JsonReferenceHandler() => Reset();
    private ReferenceResolver? _rootedResolver;
    public override ReferenceResolver CreateResolver() => _rootedResolver!;
    public void Reset(){
        _rootedResolver = new JsonReferenceResolver();
  }
}
```

and here I create the JsonSerializerOptions:

```
    private static ReferenceHandler referenceHandler = new JsonReferenceHandler();

    private static readonly JsonSerializerOptions options = new()
    {
        Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping,
        WriteIndented = true,
        ReferenceHandler = referenceHandler,
        IncludeFields = true
    };
```

For serializsation:

> JsonSerializer.SerializeToNode(objectToSave, options);

For deserialization:

> JsonSerializer.Deserialize(typeconfigstring, options)

I added some console outputs to the methods of my custom resolver:

- GetReference: is called during serialization.
- AddReference: is called during deseialization, but not for all $ids, in the JSON.
- ResolveReference: is never called.

Are I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster.

Comment: Are you running code on same machine in same application?  You may be using a different library for serialize and deserialize.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem.  If I serialize an an array containing the same instance of a model three times, e.g. `var array = new [] { model, model, model };`, then if I round-trip the array with your options the deserialized array will also have one distinct entry, as required: `Assert.That(deserializedArray!.Distinct().Count() == 1);`.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/abtyJh.  Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] as indicated in [ask].  Thanks!

Comment: I notice your `JsonSerializerOptions options` are `private static readonly`.  Is there any chance you are have a threading / concurrency bug where one thread is resetting your `JsonReferenceHandler` while another thread is serializing or deserializing?

Comment: I do not think there is some threading problem. That I do not get any logs from the method "ResolveReference" is the problem. Even if the JsonReferenceHandler has been resetted, the method should be called.
I set up a small project to reproduce the problem, but there everything semms to work correctly, so I need to find the differences between my example an the main project...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the mistake:

I missed the private setter of my property, so during deserialization nothing was set.

With a public setter or [JsonInlude] eyerything works like expected.